# First order non linear ODE,

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation

$$t=x'\sqrt{(x')^2+1}$$

I tried squaring and making the substitution $p=x'$. 
I get something like $t^2=p^4+p^2$. Then I differentiate w.r.t to $t$ and try solving that, but I simply end up getting the same equation I have started with. Basically I solve nothing. I feel like there is something really easy I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring both sides yields
$$
t^{2}=x^{\prime}(t)^{2}\left(x^{\prime}(t)^{2}+1\right)=x^{\prime}(t)^{4}+x^{\prime}(t)^{2}.
$$
Letting $y(t)=x^{\prime}(t)^{2}\geq0$,
$$
t^{2}=y(t)^{2}+y(t),
$$
we can solve for $y(t)$ (keeping only the nonnegative solution)
$$
y(t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{4t^{2}+1}-1\right).
$$
In terms of $x(t)$,
$$
x^{\prime}(t)=\frac{\sqrt{\sqrt{4t^{2}+1}-1}}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$
Now, integrate both sides:
$$
x(T)-x(0)=\int_{0}^{T}x^{\prime}(t)dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{T}\sqrt{\sqrt{4t^{2}+1}-1}.
$$

You can [compute the last integral symbolically](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%3DD%5Bx%5Bt%5D,t%5D*Sqrt%5BD%5Bx%5Bt%5D,t%5D%5E2%2B1%5D), or perhaps with great patience (which I lack).

(I made the assumption that an initial value is given at $t_0=0$, but you simply replace $0$ above with an arbitrary $t_0$, or write the solution as an indeterminate integral)